# Intervisibility tool does not consider the obstruction in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, 3d-analyst, visibility

I have a 3D point outside a building as shown in the figure. I utilized the [Construct Sight Lines](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/3d-analyst-toolbox/construct-sight-lines.htm) tool to generate lines between the point and points which represent the vertices of the building.

Now, on running the [Intervisibility](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/3d-analyst-toolbox/intervisibility.htm) tool with the building (multipatch) as an obstruction, all the lines are assigned a value of 1 as shown in the figure, which means the end and start points are visible.

The obstruction is not considered.

[image]

Comment: When you used the Intervisibility tool what parameter values did you use?